# Define structure in golang

Tags: go

I am working on a project in which I receive payload data in the following format:

```
"name":"John",
"date":"2022-04-14",
"price":200,
"dependencies":[
{
"element_1":{
"items":[2,4],
"pricing":[1,2]
}
},
{
"element_2":{
"items":[5,4],
"pricing":[1,6]
}
}
]
```

How should I define the struct for this? If you know please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: map[string]interface{} is the most generic way

Comment: Are there always two elements, or can the elements continue indefinitely, i.e. `element_x`?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj I have to read "element_1" key. If I use map[string]interface{}. I have to type assertion which I want to avoid.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden Currently the maximum elements can be 5 but I don't want it to be static.

Comment: Use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to get some schema ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part

```json
"dependencies":[
{
"element_1":{
"items":[2,4],
"pricing":[1,2]
}
},
{
"element_2":{
"items":[5,4],
"pricing":[1,6]
}
}
]
```

Looks like

```golang
type XXX struct {
  Dependencies []map[string]Dependency `json:"dependencies"`
}

type Dependency struct {
Items []int // json…
Pricing []int // json…
}
```

But I am not sure… if element_x is dynamic or not. If it is predefined, ok.

Answer (score 1):

If your json is

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "date": "2022-04-14",
    "price": 200,
    "dependencies":
    [
        {
            "element_1":
            {
                "items":
                [
                    2,
                    4
                ],
                "pricing":
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "element_2":
            {
                "items":
                [
                    5,
                    4
                ],
                "pricing":
                [
                    1,
                    6
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can create struct like this

```
type DemoStruct struct {
    Name         string       `json:"name"`        
    Date         string       `json:"date"`        
    Price        int64        `json:"price"`       
    Dependencies []Dependency `json:"dependencies"`
}

type Dependency struct {
    Element1 *Element `json:"element_1,omitempty"`
    Element2 *Element `json:"element_2,omitempty"`
}

type Element struct {
    Items   []int64 `json:"items"`  
    Pricing []int64 `json:"pricing"`
}
```

Comment: The elements can be undefined.

Comment: @Sahildeep you may use pointers along with omitempty tag.